# My Javascript functions aren't working when adding more than 9 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this page developed for listing people out. When you click on their names I have another section built out to hold the content of that individual. It has been working fine, but now I have a need to add more than 9 people to the list.

When Adding the 10th element you can no longer click the name on the left and load the correct persons information. It is selected and jumps to the #1 element. I have provided the code below and a link to the page on https://github.com/supasmo/Management-Testing.

I need help with correcting this problem so it can take on as many people as I need to add to the list. Thanks in Advance for any suggestions.

JS

```
management = {
    debug: true,
    defaultItem: 1,
    currentItem: 0,
    bios: ".bios .bio",
    bio: "#bio",
    manager: ".managers div.bio",
    managerLinks: ".managers a",
    topLinks: ".bio a.top",
    paging: ".bio .paging",
    bioNames: ".bio h1",
    yellowArrowSrc: "public/assets/common/arrow-link.png",
    blueArrowSrc: "public/assets/common/arrow-link-blue.png",

    init: function() {
        this.log("management.init()");

        // count bios
        this.bioCount = $(this.bios).length;
        this.log("Found " + this.bioCount + " bios.");

        // hide bios, names and "top" links, show paging links
        $(this.bios).hide();
        $(this.topLinks).hide();
        $(this.bioNames).hide();
        $(this.paging).show();

        // show default item
        this.showItem(this.defaultItem);

        // adjust bio links
        $(this.managerLinks).click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            management.linkClick($(this).parent());
        });

        // enable next and prev clicks
        $(this.paging + " .next").css("cursor", "pointer").click(function() {
            management.nextClick();
        });
        $(this.paging + " .prev").css("cursor", "pointer").click(function() {
            management.prevClick();
        });
    },

    prevClick: function() {
        this.log("prevClick()");
        newItem = this.currentItem - 1;
        if (newItem < 1) {
            newItem = this.bioCount;
        }
        this.showItem(newItem);
    },

    nextClick: function() {
        this.log("nextClick()");
        newItem = this.currentItem + 1;
        if (newItem > this.bioCount) {
            newItem = 1;
        }
        this.showItem(newItem);
    },

    linkClick: function(which) {
        this.showItem(which.attr("class").substr(3, 1));
    },

    showItem: function(which) {
        this.log("showItem(" + which + ")");
        if (which == this.currentItem) {
            this.log("--> aborted: item is already showing");
        } else {
            $(this.bio + this.currentItem).hide();
            $(this.bio + which).show();

            $(this.manager).removeClass("current");
            $(this.manager + which).addClass("current");

            $(this.manager + " img.arrow").attr("src", this.yellowArrowSrc);
            $(this.manager + which + " img.arrow").attr("src", this.blueArrowSrc);

            this.currentItem = which;
        }
    },

    log: function(message) {
        if (this.debug) {
            console.log(message);
        }
    },

    // ===== End of Object =====

    endOfObject: 1
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    management.init();
});
```

Comment: `this.showItem(which.attr("class").substr(3, 1));` The magic numbers, what do they mean (hint — numbers after 9 are more than one digit in base 10)

Comment: Yeah looking at the HTML, minitech is right. He's hard coded the elements, but also the substr values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.showItem(which.attr("class").substr(3, 1));
```

This part doesn’t work for more than one digit, and is just not the right way to do that in general, since the order of classes in `class` is not supposed to matter. At the very least, you should use a data attribute:

```
<div class="bio" data-bio="10">
```

```
this.showItem(which.data("bio"));
```

If you want to be substringy, though, you’ve got a perfectly good link:

```
// adjust bio links
$(this.managerLinks).click(function(e) {
    management.linkClick(this);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```
linkClick: function(which) {
    this.showItem(which.getAttribute("href").match(/\d+/)[0]);
},
```